# Djando social_django запрос к таблице

Tags: django

Нужно получить строки из таблице `social_auth_usersocialauth` которая находиться в БД. Таблица создана `social_django`.

Пробовал `from social_django.models import social_auth_usersocialauth` но так не находит таблицу.

Как мне обратиться к таблице `social_auth_usersocialauth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth
```